# elantech touchpad not detected on gigabyte laptop

Tags: drivers, mouse, touchpad, elantech

My laptop's touchpad doesn't seem to be detected at all on my Gigabyte P35 laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. I think it's an Elantech touchpad. Any ideas on how to make it work?

Here are some details:

```
$ uname -a
Linux cyrille-gigabyte 3.16.0-031600-generic #201408031935 SMP Sun Aug 3 23:36:11 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have an external USB mouse connected here:

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer Diamondback 3G                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam                                 id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

idem here

```
$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep Name
N: Name="Lid Switch"
N: Name="Sleep Button"
N: Name="Power Button"
N: Name="Razer Razer Diamondback 3G"
N: Name="HD WebCam"
N: Name="Video Bus"
N: Name="Video Bus"
N: Name="HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
N: Name="HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7"
N: Name="HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8"
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Mic"
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Headphone"
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
```

Let me know if you need further details on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on my new Gigabyte P35 v2 laptop. After a lot of searching, I came across this kernel bug thread:

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=81331

After downloading the patch in post 135 in that thread ( https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=145981 ) I applied this to the latest upstream kernel (3.17.0 at the time of this writing), recompiled and booted-- and now the touchpad gets recognized and works fine from a cold boot. (2-finger scrolling, and toggling the touchpad on and off with Fn+F6 works too!)

It's being recognized thus:

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=000e Version=0000
N: Name="ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event5
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e420 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=661800011000003
```

Comment: @Stephen can you expand how to apply the patch? With a link at least? Thank you!

Comment: another method that seems to work if your touchpad only works intermittently: power off your laptop for at least *60 seconds* (55 won't work), and reboot. see https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=81331#c35

Comment: Sometimes its the simple of things Tried patch updated kernel to 4.3 and tried about 10 things and in the end it was the Fn+F6 or in my case Fn+F7 doh

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue. Touchpad is not listed in xinput. I've just bought a `lenovo ideapad 320E-15IKB D` laptop. The touchpad is working fine in windows 10 pro after installing drivers but i tried installing ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 both and touchpad doesn't work at all. Its elantech as per the drivers i installed in windows. How do i apply this patch. is there a link available?