# How to apply an "undocumented" kernel patch

Tags: kernel, touchpad, patch, elantech

I am unable to use the touchpad on my new GigaByte P35 v2.  I seem to have the problem documented here ([elantech touchpad not detected on gigabyte laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529797/elantech-touchpad-not-detected-on-gigabyte-laptop)), and here (https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=81331), which has been recently fixed here (https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=161431).

Being a new forum member, I do not have enough reputation points to post a follow-up question to the other thread on this forum.

I have read the top 15 or so hits on Google for applying the patch, but none address this specific issue.  Most have a broader focus or expect that the patch comes with some instructions.

I have downloaded the sources for my current kernel version (3.13.0) and have the patch file.

Could someone please tell me how to complete the process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

1. Copy the patch file somewhere. I copied it to `/usr/src/linux-3.13.0`
2. Apply the patch (you need to make `/usr/src/linux-3.13.0` your current directory) .  Tell patch to ignore the first segment of the internal pathing

   ```
   sudo patch -p 1 -u < elantech_trackpad_patch_for_laptops_v2.patch 
   patching file Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt
   Hunk #1 succeeded at 1138 (offset -132 lines).
   patching file drivers/input/serio/i8042-x86ia64io.h
   Hunk #1 succeeded at 721 (offset -14 lines).
   Hunk #2 succeeded at 1017 (offset -29 lines).
   patching file drivers/input/serio/i8042.c
   Hunk #2 succeeded at 792 (offset -2 lines)
   ```
3. Build the kernel

   ```
   make localmodconfig
   make menuconfig   // just accepted the defaults
   make -j3 deb-pkg
   ```
4. Install the kernel

   ```
   cd ../
   sudo dpkg -i <linux image file>
   sudo dpkg -i <linux headers file?
   ```

If anyone knows a better way to do it, please let me/the interwebs know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get kernel sources, apply patch and compile your new kernel and get it installed (you may also want to create your own rpm with it)

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I have the kernel sources and the .patch file and my question was to how to apply the patch.  

The patch file has relative pathing to the source files to receive the patches, starting with "a/".  Do I go to /usr/src/myKernelDirectory and then execute patch -u < theFile.patch?  

If so, what else do I do before compiling?